# $f: [0,1] \to [0,1],$ such that $| (f^n)'(x_0)| \leq e^{-2n}$ $\Rightarrow $ $|f^n(x_0) - f^n(x_0 + h) | \to 0,$ for $h$ small

Tags: real-analysis, functions, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a smooth function and let $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that
$$\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}f^n}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_0)\right| <e^{-2n}, \ \forall \ n\in\mathbb N,$$
where $$f^n := f \circ \ldots \circ f,\ n\ \text{times}.$$

I would like to know if the above conditions imply that there exists an open neighbourhood $U_{x_0}$ of $x_0,$ such that
$$ y\in U_{x_0}\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}|f^n(x_0) - f^n(y)| = 0. $$

Or at least, that given $\varepsilon >0,$
$$ y\in U_{x_0}\Rightarrow |f^n(x_0) - f^n(y)|\leq \varepsilon,\ \forall \ n\geq n_0. $$

---

The only idea that I had was using Taylor expansion. For every $n\in\mathbb N$ we can write
$$|f^n(x_0 + h) - f^n(x_0)| = | (f^n)'(x_0)| h + \mathcal O_n(h^2), $$
where $\mathcal O_n$ is function of order $2,$ that depends on $n.$ The problem is that

$$|f^n(x_0 + h) - f^n(x_0)| = | (f^n)'(x_0)| h + \mathcal O_n(h^2), $$
but I do not know why $\mathcal O_n(h^2),$ should be uniformly small on $n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the operator $\circ$ does? Does it mean $f^2=f(x)\,f(x)$ or maybe $f^2=f(f(x))$?

Comment: $f^2(x) = f \circ f (x) = f(f(x))$

Comment: What definition do you use for $\mathbb{N}$? Namely, sometimes zero is or isn't included. When you do include zero the inequality is always violated since $$\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}f^0}{\mathrm{d}x}(x_0)\right|=1 \nless e^{-2\,0}=1.$$ Or you need to change $<$ into $\leq$.

Comment: $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}.$

Comment: Does your first inequality need to hold for some or for all $x_0\in[0,1]$?

Comment: For some $x_0\in [0,1].$